# Convert a pipe delimited file into a hash?

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and have two questions:

(1) How do I convert a text file which has multiple data fields separated by pipe into a hash?:

```
name | student-id | maths | english | science | grade | remarks   | 
abc  |  10001     |  90   | 80      | 80      | A+    | excellent |
.
.
.
```

(2) Additionally, if I have a new column which is another hash:

```
name | student-id | maths | english | science | grade | remarks   | options     |
abc  |  10001     |  90   | 80      | 80      | A+    | excellent | <condition> |
.
.
.
```

Where, `| Options |` is another hash of:

```
| Stream      | Average   |
| Com Science |  90       |
| Elec Eng    |  85       |
| Mech Eng    |  80       |
.
.
.
```

I want to list all the students who qualify for all the different streams based on their average scores.

Comment: What are the keys and values?

Comment: @newruby: Use four spaces to indent the code parts of your question.

Comment: So, basically, you have fields which are pipe-separated tables themselves? Meaning that each row in master table can have multiple rows in "options" sub-table?

Comment: Yes, each row can have multiple rows in "options" sub-table.

Comment: Table-1: student-id + name (key), rest of the fields are values.

Comment: Table-2: stream (key), rest of the fields are values

Comment: You keep using the word "hash", but I'm not sure you understand what it means: `if I have a new column which is another hash` and `Where, | Options | is another hash of`. Also, you really need to show a more-complete example of the data you're working with, and an example of the desired output hash, along with some sample code showing you've attempted to solve what really sounds like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, use Ruby's built-in CSV class. Specify the `:col_sep` value as `'|'` to override the default value of `','`. Both [`CSV.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) and [`CSV.open`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open) allow you to specify that option.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction, I'm able to use "smarter_csv" gem and do exactly what I needed.